# Pass client COM port data to Web Form on Remote IIS Using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, model-view-controller, webforms

I have 3 Digital Wind Readers connected on 3 Windows 11 Machines through COM Port. Using Winforms Application in C#, I was able to read the Wind Speed and show it in a Textbox Control.

What I want is to use Windows Service using C# to pass the COM port data (Wind Speed) to a Textbox Control on a Web Form in a Web Application hosted on a Remote IIS using C# as well.

See this picture for more details:
[image]

Where should I start? I was trying to use the code behind in my Web application (asp.net), but it shows the COM Port data that is connected the IIS server only.

**Note:**
The data of each client machine should not be appear on other clients in the web form.

Comment: When you read the winds peed of each of the wind readers on each of the client machines, that is the point you need to query the com port data for THAT computer and send it back TOGETHER with the wind speed to the server... I would hazard a guess that the com port data is not available to external devices/computers...

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me the most simple way would be to send the wind speed to a database, with the 1, 2,3 (or some other type of wind reader id) to be saved in that table.

At that point, it is a simple matter to have users login to your site, and choose wind reader 1-3, and then you can display the information in a text box, or grab a nice control like gauge.js, and display it in one of these:

[image]

So, it not clear the time resolution you need/want here? Say once a 1 second, or maybe every 5 seconds?

So, a simple timer dropped into a page could then trigger (every 2 or 5 seconds), read the database, and pull the top 1 reading by date/time and pull based on the "wind reader id", and display that in a text box, or as noted say the above gauge control.

And it not clear if you want to keep "history" data, say readings for every hour, 15 minutes or whatever? So, you might in your code say update the SAME top most record in the database, and if the 15 (or 30 minute) span is greater, then start a new record. So, say with 1/2 hour saving of history data, that would only be say 48 records per day per meter.).

So, you update the "last" or "top most" data point in the database, and keep updating that one record until such time 30 minutes passes, and then you start updating the next new record.

The "meter" or text box update thus only has to do a

```
select top 1 WindSpeed from tblWind WHERE MeterID = 1 ORDER BY WindDate DESC.
```

So, with such a design, you get those data logging as a bonus, and the wind speed display simple has to take the top most data record based on date/time column sorted descending.

So, that one computer (or are their 3) that readds the com port data? it simple need to be able to update the database - the same one that drives the web site. So, I see little if any need to have the web site itself read the com ports and keeping that hardware separate makes for a more reliable system anyway (you don't want a web site or web page reading com ports, and that not at all a good setup given how the web page page life cycles work anyway).

So, details such as how you get that computer with the COM ports to "write out" data to the database? Well, it depends on your networking and other setups. But, you could certainly add a web API (web end point) to the web site (that way, it could be hosted anywhere - and not need a direct connection to the com port computer. So, then the computer running the COM ports could use that web api to hit the web site, and then write out the one data point.

However, if that computer with COM ports can be part of the same network (where the SQL database resides), then it would be far more easy to have the COM port computer write directly to the database.

So, if it is "harder" to have the com port computer be part of the same network as the database? Then create a web api that the com port computer can call/use/consume to write out the 1 datapoint. That way, any low cost web hosting could be used, and no direct connection from the com port computer to database would be required.

And with such a setup, then 10 people could easy be viewing one of the 3 meters - there not really a limit here, only that the user is required to choose a meter to see/view (or perhaps you base this meter choice based on their logon id to the site).

As noted, in place of text box, you could use one of the above "gauge" meters. They are very "springing" in how they bounce around (when you feed the control a new value). They give a rather mechanical feel to how those gauge "move" to a new value. And you could have a admin user, or other users that could see/view all 3 gauges if you wanted.

So, the "instant" you have each computer with the COM port write out the data to the database? Then from that point onwards, your web site does not need or have or worry about ANY concept of a COM port, but only that of hitting the database to pull the top most record of the particular "wind" machine number you want.

And it probably stands to reason that you want to log + save the wind data anyway. As noted, you can pick a 15 minute, or even 5 minute interval, and thus can over time "query" the average wind speed for the last hour, day, or even week.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not what I asked for. I want to pass the COM port data to a textbox on a web form and only the client that is connected to the COM port can see the data that is passed to the textbox, and other clients see only their data, etc. So, I don't want to save data in DB and then select the last inserted data from it and show it on the web form.

Comment: Well, then you adopting a poor design, and you will suffer as a result. I would suggest the database approach. You don't mention if you want to update that text box say every one second, or you want it to update WHEN the computer sends that data. If you are looking to update (push notification) from the com computer to the text box in real time, based on when the COM computer sends the data? Then you have to adopt a web socket approach. In near all cases, that means to use SignalR. So, SignalR is a good approach. you can start here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: As a follow-up? Your goal is not a poor design if your looking to have real time update of that text box - or maybe a cool Guage control. So for say a page in which both users type and you have real time updating of what both users are typing? Or in your quest to have real time updates on that web page? Then you can do this by using web sockets. However using signalR library does all that wireing up of those web sockets for you.  It really comes down to how frequently you want the updates to occur. So my suggestion of database still stands,  but this comes down to what kind of updating desired

Comment: As I understand, if I use SignalR, the data of each client will appear on any client machine that is browsing the same webform at the same time. Is this true? If yes, then it doesn't help me with my project as I want any client to see the data of the COM port that is connected to its machine.

Comment: Any web page can display data from one of the 3 inputs.  You could have one web page that asks for a given "channel" (say 1 to 3) and thus display that in real time. So, no requirement here. And I'm confused over "client to see data of the COM port that is connected to its machine". The data logging of the 3 COM inputs is 100% separate from that of any user of the web site using a browser. The end web user's don't have a COM port active or connected, so this is confusing? The concept of the COM data from the 3 data loggers is 100% separate from that of web users that want to see data right?

Comment: I mean, think of a chat site. You can have 20 people log into the web site, and then any (or all) of the people can enter a chat room 1-5. Those in any of those 1-5 rooms when they type will see their typing (in real time) and any other who entered that room also sees and can type.  But the concept of 1-5 rooms, or 20 or whatever is your choice as developer.  So I fail to see how each client will  have a com port - they do not, and the browser can't touch nor use the COM port. So, those 3 inputs are sent to site, but users of site can choose to view any (1-3) for which data stream they see

Comment: so the term "client" here has to be defined. In my context, client means a end user logging into the site. You have 3 data streams, and 100 people logging into the site can thus choose to see or pick data stream 1-3 to view.  As noted, it not clear how often that data stream for device 1-3 is updated. Regardless, the concept of a user/client hitting the site and seeing data stream 1-3 is 100% separate from those machines 1-3 that sends a data stream to the site. Those data loggers (1-3) can't be browser based here, but will require some type of network socket connection to the web server.